# How can thin horizontal lines be added between each row in a grayscale image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I need to create an nth-order Hadamard matrix, row double it, within each row randomly permute the elements of the matrix, and then display it. So far, I have accomplished all of these things. What I end up with when I `imshow(matrix)` is a nice picture of black and white boxes. *But I haven't figured out how to insert a fine line to divide each row.* I can create something like the first image on the left, but not the image on the right (these are Figures 1 and 2 from [this paper](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~gehm/pubs/ApplOpt.46.4932.pdf))

[image]   [image]

￼Any help or comments would be thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've found using vector approaches (e.g., `patch` and `rectangle`) for this sort of problem unnecessarily challenging. I think that it's more straightforward to build a new image. This avoids floating-point rounding issues and other things that crop up with vector graphics. My solution below relies on some functions in the Image Processing Toolbox, but is simple and fast:

```
% Create data similarly to @TryHard
H = hadamard(48);
C = (1+[H;-H])/2;
rng(0); % Set seed
C(:) = C(randperm(numel(C))); % For demo, just permute all values, not rows

% Scale image and lines
scl = 10; % Amount to vertically scale each row
pad = 2;  % Number of pixels to add between each row
C = imresize(C,scl,'nearest');
C = blockproc(C,[scl size(C,2)],@(x)[x.data;zeros(pad,size(C,2))]);
C = C(1:end-pad,:); % Remove last line added

% Dispay image
imshow(C)
```

This results in an image like this

[image: imshow image]

The `scl` and `pad` parameters can be easily adjusted to obtain different sizes and relative sizes. You can call `imresize(...,'nearest')` again after adding the lines to further scale the image if desired. The [`blocproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) line could potentially be made more efficient with various options (see the help). It could also be replaced by calls to [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) and [`col2im`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/col2im.html), which possibly could be faster, if messier.

Comment: wow you make it look so simple!  You even shortened the row-doubling process.  Thank you for your response and the insight, it helps immensely!

Comment: @StrugglingGradStudent: You'll need to make sure I did that part correctly. I really don't know what you need with the Hadamard matrix, I was just trying to create some data to provide a demo of the rest of the code. Glad that it was helpful. Let me know if it ends up solving your problem.

Comment: @StrugglingGradStudent Please consider accepting the answer if it did what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

I did not try the code, but I think that something like that should work:

```
sizeOfACube = 6;
numberOfRows = 47;    

RGB = imread('image.png');
RGB = imresize(A, [(numRows+numberOfRows) numCols]);


for i=1:1:NumberOfRows 
    RGB(i*6,:,:) = 0;
end

imagesc(RGB);
imwrite(RGB,'newImage.png');
```

with:
sizeOfAcube the size of one cube on the QRcode.
numRows and numCols the number of Rows and Column of the original image.

Comment: Thank you @R. Bergamote.  However, your code did not work, but it gives me something to think about.  I really need to learn more about matlab in general, and seeing various functions in context helps that.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use patches, for instance as follows:

```
% set up example array
xl = 24; yl = xl;
[X Y] = find(hadamard(xl)==1);
% generate figure
figure, hold on
for ii=1:length(X)
    patch(X(ii) + [0 0 1 1],Y(ii) + [0.1 0.9 0.9 0.1],[1 1 1],'Edgecolor',[1 1 1])
end
axis([0 xl+1 0 yl+1])
axis('square')
```

The patch command `patch(x,y, color)` accepts the vertices of the polygon element as `x` and `y`. In this example you can modify the term `[0.1 0.9 0.9 0.1]` to set the thickness of the bounding black line.

This generates

[image]

**Edited**

For the particular instance provided by the OP:

```
H=Hadamard(48); %# now to row-double the matrix 
A=(1+H)/2;
B=(1-H)/2;
C=[A; B]; %# the code below randomly permutes elements within the rows of the matrix 
[nRows,nCols] = size(C); 
[junk,idx] = sort(rand(nRows,nCols),2); %# convert column indices into linear indices 
idx = (idx-1)*nRows + ndgrid(1:nRows,1:nCols); %# rearrange whatever matrix 
E = C; 
E(:) = E(idx);
[X Y] = find(logical(E));
xl = length(X);
yl = length(Y);
figure, hold on
for ii=1:xl
     rectangle('Position',[X(ii) Y(ii)+.2 1 0.8],'facecolor',[1 1 1],'edgecolor',[1 1 1])
end
axis([0 max(X)+1 0 max(Y)+1])
axis('square')
set(gca,'color',[0 0 0])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[],'YTickLabel',[],'XTick',[],'YTick',[])
```

This example uses `rectangle` instead of patch to generate sharp corners.

The image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response!  @Try Hard, your results looks promising, but when I try your code all I get is a blank figure.  I've manipulated it a little bit, and I can get outlines of boxes to show up, but, being very unfamiliar with matlab, I am not sure what else needs to be modified.  My current code to generate the matrix is as follows in the following comment...

Comment: H=Hadamard(48)
    
    %# now to row-double the matrix
    A=(1+H)/2
    B=(1-H)/2
    C=[A; B]

    %# the code below randomly permutes elements within the rows of the matrix
    [nRows,nCols] = size(C);

    [~,idx] = sort(rand(nRows,nCols),2);

    %# convert column indices into linear indices
idx = (idx-1)*nRows + ndgrid(1:nRows,1:nCols);

%# rearrange whatever matrix
E = C;
E(:) = E(idx)
imshow(E)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Using your code, I can reproduce the image you have posted.  I have two concerns, many of the black and white squares have rounded corners, and some do not.  I am not sure why this is.  For my application, I will need to make sure that there are nothing but right angles and well-defined corners.  My second concern is that the overall matrix/image has twice as many columns now (96 instead of 48).  Once again, I sincerely appreciate all of your help with this @Try Hard!

Comment: Of course, I will need to make sure that I can use the code for any order Hadamard matrix, so there is nothing special about N=48.

Comment: About the rounded corners: I see that too and will look into it, or you can post it as a separate question (I have not searched for an answer online, someone may have noticed this before)

Comment: Thank you!  Meanwhile, I will look over your code again and try to understand it better.  I truly appreciate this!

Comment: Regarding doubling the size of the array, that follows from the concatenation operation here: `C=[A; B];` Since I don't really understand the purpose of that step (or your algorithm, although I can guess) I cannot provide guidance as to how to fix the size issue.

Comment: @StrugglingGradStudent I found a workaround that uses `rectangle`. You'll have to work around a little with the matlab graphics tools, but I think this answers your question! :>)

Comment: Still not sure about why corners are round when rendering rectangles with `patch`...

Comment: Please see my attempt to resolve this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067304/how-to-avoid-curved-corners-in-rectangular-patch-element-in-matlab-figure. I think `rectangle` is the simplest you can hope for with matlab (but not the best graphics solution).

Comment: thank you so much for everything that you have done and for all of the time and effort that you have put into answering my question!  I think you are right about rectangle being the way to go.  I will explore this further.  I'm sure that others will benefit from the work you have put forth here.  I can not thank you enough.  I was truly lost but now there's hope!  I will keep an eye on the question that you posted, but I think I can take it from here.  Thanks again!

Comment: @StrugglingGradStudent If it answered you question please click on the check mark next to the answer. I think horchler's answer is on the money btw.