# How to avoid curved corners in rectangular patch element in matlab figure?

Tags: matlab, graphics, rendering

When I generate a set of rectangular patches in a matlab figure, some of the rectangle edges are rendered curved or clipped rather than sharp, which is unwanted. This depends on the scale, zooming into the image tends to eliminate the effect. I thought this might have to do with an aliasing/compression effect. Curiously, using `rectangle` the problem seems to go away.

Here is an example of the problem at intermediate magnification (other problems such as dashed borders which shouldn't be there are also evident):

[image]

The code is from an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048678/how-can-thin-horizontal-lines-be-added-between-each-row-in-a-grayscale-image/18055263?noredirect=1#comment26433254_18055263):

```
H=Hadamard(48); %# now to row-double the matrix 
A=(1+H)/2;
B=(1-H)/2;
C=[A; B]; %# the code below randomly permutes elements within the rows of the matrix 
[nRows,nCols] = size(C); 
[junk,idx] = sort(rand(nRows,nCols),2); %# convert column indices into linear indices 
idx = (idx-1)*nRows + ndgrid(1:nRows,1:nCols); %# rearrange whatever matrix 
E = C; 
E(:) = E(idx);
[X Y] = find(logical(E));
xl = length(X);
yl = length(Y);
figure, hold on
for ii=1:xl
     patch(X(ii) + [0 0 1 1],Y(ii) + [0.15 0.9 0.9 0.1],[1 1 1],'Edgecolor',[1 1 1])
end
axis([0 max(X)+1 0 max(Y)+1])
axis('square')
set(gca,'color',[0 0 0])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[],'YTickLabel',[],'XTick',[],'YTick',[])
```

My questions are:
(1) Is it possible (and how) to get rid of the curved corners and other glitches of patch objects seen in the example shown, at low to intermediate degrees of magnification used to display the entire figure on screen. 
(2) Most important is to be able to generate an image file (jpg, png, pdf...) which lacks the curved corners. All formats I looked into appear to conserve the unwanted effect. Answering 2 makes answering (1) essentially unimportant, and answering (1) presumably solves (2).

**Edit**

Since the problem goes away when `rectangle` is used, this appears to be a problem with the matlab rendering engine? Note: the example was generated with R14 but the OP of the question linked to had similar problems (matlab version unknown).

I went through the various lighting and edge representation options available for patch objects but no improvement was observed.

Comment: From experience, I can tell you that you're going to run into annoying issues using a `patch`-based 3-D object solution instead of simply building a new image with integer numbers of pixels. You'll find that there are all sorts of rounding issues, some dimensions that are supposed to be the same don't end up that way, and that your patches look different at different sizes and when zoomed in. Vector graphics is hard.

Comment: @horchler Not having focused much with 3D graphics I came late to the realization that patch objects are especially for 3D rendering. Again this might be a matlab version limitation, but looking at the documentation there do not appear to be a lot of choices for drawing a 2D polygon, and 2D applications of patch are all over the documentation. Am I missing something (again because of my old matlab version)?

Comment: And mathworks is not a puny company. Are patch style graphics much improved in recent versions?

Comment: It's all OpenGL (or similar) at the core for such things. The issue is not really 2-D v.s. 3-D here (although there are plenty of bugs/issues there), but vector vs. raster.

Comment: I should add in hindsight that in addition to `rectangle` there is also `fill`, which creates a `patch` object.

Comment: Does `fill` improve anything relative to using the lower level `patch`?

Comment: @horchler The short answer would be no :>) ... curved corners are there as in patch... best seems to be rectangle.

Comment: @horchler as you pointed out it's a problem with the OpenGL renderer. Using `set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer')` helps with `fill` ... but not with `patch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a likely repeat, for instance a similar questions was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315571/how-to-prevent-the-fill-command-in-matlab-from-creating-boxes-without-corners).

The answer appears to be to avoid explicit use of `patch` when drawing rectangles. Use either `fill` or just `rectangle` instead. The following ways of generating the figure provide nearly equivalent results, as far as I could tell:

```
load had.mat % <-- load the data containing the matrix of interest in array E
[X Y] = find(logical(E));
xl = length(X);
yl = length(Y);
figure, hold on
for ii=1:xl
      rectangle('Position',[X(ii) Y(ii)+.2 1 0.8],'facecolor',[1 1 1],'edgecolor',[1 1 1])
%     fill([X(ii) X(ii) X(ii)+1 X(ii)+1], [Y(ii)+0.2 Y(ii)+0.8 Y(ii)+0.8 Y(ii)+0.2],[1 1 1],'edgecolor',[1 1 1],'marker','.','markersize',1)
end
set(gca,'color',[0 0 0])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[],'YTickLabel',[],'XTick',[],'YTick',[])
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer')
```